# How can I make this logic expression simpler?

Tags: logic

I always get some expression like this:

```
while(choice != "left" || choice != "right" || choice != "up" || choice != "down")
```

Is there a simpler way of saying it?

Comment: which languge is that ? A solution like this looks better :  while (choice not in ["left","right","up","down"] )

Answer (score 2):

This while sentence is not a good idea. It always return true. Did you mean

while(choice != "left" && choice != "right" && choice != "up" && choice != "down") ¿

If not, yo can simplify that as while(true) :)

Comment: You are missing some point. It will not enter the loop if the value is not in list. while (true) enters always.

Comment: Ah, actually i'm missing the point. Sure it always return true. :) The logic is wrong.

Comment: Hehehe sure, but for the actual question he is asking and depending of the language, your answer is the most accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var isOneOf = function isOneOf(matches, givenItem) {
    return matches.some(function (match) {
        return match === givenItem; 
    }); 
}; 

while (!isOneOf(['left', 'right', 'up', 'down'], choice)) {

    // ...continue 

}
```